# nodejs express-fileupload - wrong encoding on filename in docker environment

Tags: node.js, docker, utf-8, express-fileupload

I'm struggling with wrong encoded multipart form filenames uploaded to a nodejs backend.

Running the node application locally works as expected and the filenames arrive with propert utf-8 encoding. As soon as i run the application in a docker environment the backend receives scrambled filenames.

I'm using the `express-fileupload` package.

JSON Content in the same request is properly encoded..

Backend:

```js
router.post('/upload', async (req: any, res) => {
    let formDataFiles = req.files;
});
```

http response header seems correct as well: `content-type application/json; charset=utf-8`

I'm not sure where to look. Where does nodejs take the encoding from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok i found the solution. `express-fileupload` uses [busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy#api) under the hood. You can pass in busboy options and one of them is `defParamCharset`:

> "For multipart forms, the default character set to use for values of
> part header parameters (e.g. filename) that are not extended
> parameters (that contain an explicit charset)."

**The documentation states `Default: 'latin1'.` but in my case it was dependent on the running OS!**

If you initialize the middleware as following it should properly UTF8 encode filenames:

```js
app.use(fileUpload({
    defCharset: 'utf8',
    defParamCharset: 'utf8'
}));
```